# Install a self signed certificate in IIS 10

Tags: certificate, iis

I am sorry if I am asking about a product specific question here. I need to Install a self-signed certificate in IIS 10 (Running in Windows 10). There are many articles about how to get this done in older versions but not for IIS v10.

Is there any tool like IIS6.0 Resource Kit Tool for IIS 10? If not what is the best way that I can install a self-signed certificate in IIS 10. I am going to use this only for a development purposes.

Comment: See this TechNet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710475(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is on a server, you open the IIS Manager from the start menu. Under the connections menu on the left side, select the server. Under the IIS section showing on the right, double-click the server certificates icon.

From there you can issue cert requests, complete them, create domain and self-signed certs and so on.

You don't need any other tools.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Julian Knight was the missing piece.  Below is more detail to complete the process.

- After you create the certificate from IIS by selecting the server and using the "Server Certificates" tool..
- You then open the Website, e.g.  "Default Web Site", and edit the "Bindings" (right side of panel)
- In the bindings you need to add the protocol HTTPS and select your newly created certificate.

NOTE: Ensure your computer name is legal.   e.g. It may not contain an underscore.